# unsed import statement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am currently creating a meme generator and i keep getting this message

unused import statement

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

What does this mean and how do i solve this problem ?

Comment: It means we will need a code...

Comment: @404notfound- i have now added the code

Comment: Probably line `BottomPictureFragment bottomFragment = (BottomPictureFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);` is problematic so add BottomPicureFragment code (i think that imports and class declaration will be enough).

Comment: @404notfound- when i run the code the following error messsage is displayed " cannot find symbol method getsupportFragmentManager" ?

Comment: @404notfound- i have ammended the code

Comment: @404not- still having problems

Comment: Could you tell at least what problem you have now? It is the same all the time? Something changed?

Comment: @404motfound - i get the error message cannot resolve method getsupportfragmentmanager ?

Comment: Firstly remove `fragment. ` from createMeme method

Comment: @404notfound- done that but i still am having issues , can we disccus more in one of he meeting rooms ?

Comment: @404notfound- Still having issues i have removed the fragment. form the creatememe method

Comment: You could try capitalizing the method name correctly.

Comment: @kevin - what does that mean apologies i am new to this

Comment: @404- i am totally lost , my code is not working

Comment: @user1727257 Java is case-sensitive.  If you meant `getSupportFragmentManager`, then `getsupportfragmentmanager` is wrong.

Comment: @kevin- still no joy

Answer (score 0):

com.exaample.curtis.memegenerator.Bottom pictureFragment might be extending from the android support library.

Try using

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.
```

include this in your dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: @Jim-added the above but still having issues ?

Comment: I see now that you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.   getSupportFragmentManager(). That is 

BottomPictureFragment bottomFragment = (BottomPictureFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

Comment: still having issues ?

Comment: Could you try checking the fragment class of the object retrieved? You might simply be retrieving a wrong fragment.

Fragment f  = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
System.out.println(f.getClass().getSimpleName());

Comment: still having issues ?

Comment: where in my code should i check the fragemnt class of the objcect received ?

Comment: `@Override
 public void createMeme(String top, String bottom) {

Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2); 

System.out.println(f.getClass().getSimpleName());

BottomPictureFragment bottomFragment = (BottomPictureFragment) getsupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
  bottomFragment.setTopMemeText(top,bottom);
 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82858/discussion-between-user1727257-and-jim-coven).

Comment: still having problems

Comment: still having problems i removed the fragment from the creatememe method

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so taking answer in one place:
Your fragment need to extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
Your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`
In gradle you need to have 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`
or `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'`